# what is the complexity of accessing a node in a graph generated by neo4j?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, nosql, complexity-theory, neo4j

I consider working with `dbpedia` and use `neo4j` for this purpose. I have 2 things I don't understand:

1. What is the complexity of accessing a node in the graph?
2. If I have a huge `DB` such as `dbpedia` any search for a node would
   take `O(|E|+|V|)` ?

I mean access as random access to a node in the graph, are the nodes are hashed to be accessed in `O(1)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing by ID is O(1) accessing via an index is usually O(log(n)) scanning through the db is O(n) and accessing relationships of a node is usually O(1) too.

That said you should make sure that your hot dataset is in the mmio buffers and the caches, see:

- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/embedded-configuration.html
- http://video.neo4j.org/4ALA/0719-hardware-sizing-with-neo4j/